# Get the name of the active excel workbook in c#

Tags: c#, excel

I'm looking for the easiest way to get the active workbook of Excel with c#.

I have a small c# app that needs to write data to an already open excel workbook.

The program will then copy data from c# Comboxes into certain rows in a certain column of the active sheet of the active workbook.

Most of the documentation and videos I've seen are loading an excel file and then doing something with it. I need to work with an already open excel workbook, it is possible that the user may have multiple excel workbooks open at the time.

I'm working with Excel 2016 (32 and 64 bit) and visual studio 2017.

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: Is this going to become another unanswered question? Should I post this somewhere else?

Comment: That didn't seem to fix the issue. I still can't get even one workbook to load into a combobox.